# Render Partial Using jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, partial-views

I'm trying to render a partial using jQuery in MVC3. I want to do it my changed the HTML in a section so it can be updated when a dropdown's selection changes.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#partial-6").html(@Html.Partial("_Edit",Model.Groups[0]));

});
```

Doesn't modify the section when the page is loaded. Just says what I typed there " I am partial"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless the asp code is adding quotes, you will need to do so. Otherwise you aren't passing a string into the `.html()` function:

```
$(function(){
    $('#drop-down-id').on('change', function () {
        $("#partial-6").html('@Html.Partial("_Edit",Model.Groups[0])');
    });
});
```

This will put the same code into the `#partial-6` element each time the `#drop-down-id` element is changed. If you want to actually change the information you are putting in the `#partial-6` element, you will need to make an AJAX call to return the partial from the server.

```
$(function(){
    $('#drop-down-id').on('change', function () {
        $.get('path/to/server-side.asp', { id : $(this).val() }, function (serverResponse) {
            $("#partial-6").html(serverResponse);
        });
    });
});
```

This will create a GET request for a server-side script that is sent with the GET variable, `id`, which is set to the value of the drop-down that triggered the code.

Note that `.on()` is new in jQuery 1.7 and in this case is the same as `.bind()`.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I just don't really understand. What file would this 'path/to/server-side.asp' be? Is this a controller action?

Comment: Sorry, I know almost nothing of `asp.net`. However what you want to do is get the HTML of a partial with an AJAX call.